# How to use SwitchToFrame in Selenium, Rstudio?

Tags: r, selenium, phantomjs, rstudio

I have just started using R (version 3.2.1) and RStudio (version 0.99.465) on Windows 7.

I am currently facing the error as shown below (error as shown from switchtoFrame).

```
 Error:      Summary: NoSuchFrame
 Detail: A request to switch to a frame could not be satisfied because the frame could not be found.
 class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException
```

I can run my code individually (line by line) to log in currently, however, if I just run my script, the error above will appear.
I tried to add setTimeout(), to wait for the iframe to appear, however, it seems that it doesn't work as well.

**Code**

```
appURL <- "http://www.trademap.org/Country_SelCountry_MQ_TS.aspx"
RSelenium::startServer()
library("RSelenium")
#Open headless driver phantom(), to use Chrome,etc
pJS <- phantom()
remDr<- remoteDriver(browserName="phantomjs")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(appURL)

#Log in to ITC 
webElem<-remDr$findElement(using="css","#ctl00_MenuControl_marmenu_login")$clickElement()
webElem<-remDr$setTimeout(type="script",10000)
webElem<-remDr$switchToFrame("iframe_login")
webElem<-remDr$findElement(using="id","ctl00_PageContent_Login1_UserName")$sendKeysToElement (list("myusername"))
webElem<-remDr$findElement(using="id","ctl00_PageContent_Login1_Password")$sendKeysToElement (list("mypassword"))
webElem<-remDr$findElement(using="id","ctl00_PageContent_Login1_Button")$clickElement()
#show the screen
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

I would appreciate your guidance in this matter.

Comment: Please add the version of R too.

Comment: "R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)"